# Google search console, video outside the view port when video tag is animated

Tags: html, google-index

I have a webpage that contains a video. The video is in the middle of the page and is animated so it only appears when the user scrolls down a bit.
It seems that google does not recognize the video so I see the following error.

> video outside the view port

Obviously if I disable animations on the video everything works fine but is there a way to keep the animation and fix the problem?

the web page: [the page](https://telecard.ir)